# Не удаётся подключиться к MySql

Tags: mysql

Пытаюсь подключиться к локальной БД. Хочу сделать так, чтобы доступ к БД был из под всей ЛВС, но если указать в MySQL в настройках юзера в столбце Host 'localhost', то я могу локально подключиться c ПК, на котором установлена БД, а если указываю '%', то не могу получить доступ.

Разве параметр '%' не должен означать подключение с любого хоста? Если нет, то как это сделать?

Результат `SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user;`

[image: Результат SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user]

Сообщение при подключении через консоль:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `если указываю '%', то не могу получить доступ` Лучше покажите, что выводит `SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user;`...

Comment: Отлично... а теперь покажите, каким именно пользователем подключаетесь, и какое сообщение получаете. Желательно, чтобы подключение выполнялось пусть и с другого хоста, но штатным MySQL.EXE. Так сразу видны и строка запуска, и не переосмысленное чем-то сообщение...

Comment: Ну вариантов-то осталось всего две штуки. Первый - неверный пароль. Второй - нет прав на БД по умолчанию. Попробуйте пересоздать пользователя (DROP/CREATE USER) и заново дать ему необходимые права (GRANT).

Comment: @Akina, это уже третий пользователь которого я создал, у него есть все те же права, что и у пользователя root. Пароль тоже верный, я его в коде прописал в строке подключения(На руте такой же пароль. при указании логина "root" всё работает). Проблеме в том, что когда в графе хост стоит не 'localhost', а '%', то не удаётся подключиться к БД.

Comment: `у него есть все те же права, что и у пользователя root` - добавлены явно оператором GRANT? или так, ветром надуло?

Comment: Добавлены оператором GRANT

Comment: Проверьте, добавлены ли права на БД, которая устанавливается как текущая по умолчанию. Либо смените БД по умолчанию на ту, на которую гарантированно есть права. Да, и версию сервера укажите, на всякий случай...

Comment: У пользователя admin2 есть "ALL PRIVILEGES" на БД "test". Версия сервера MySql: 10.1.21-MariaDB